# I have to take backup of all my files in Windows

Tags: boot, backup, windows-10, error-handling

There's a boot error in my Windows 10 OS, so I'm trying to take its backup while accessing the disk from Ubuntu.

But I'm getting this error mentioned in the image. Please help.

[image]

Comment: Did you try to mount with the ro option?

Comment: Can you please tell me how to mount with the ro option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a terminal window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>), create a mountpoint:

```
mkdir ~/ntfs
```

Mount sda2 to ntfs (this will be a subdirectory of your home directory:

```
sudo mount -t ntfs -o ro /dev/sda2 ~/ntfs
```

Comment: Thank you very much...... It worked.